# Download full KML from Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, kml

I have Google Map with about 1200 points. When I try to save it as KML or view in Google Earth there is only 1000 point. Is there a way (for example using some API) to download all points (I don't need KML - I just want coordinates with description - it may be in some other format)?

Map can be found [here](https://maps.google.pl/maps/ms?gl=pl&ie=UTF8&oe=UTF8&t=h&msa=0&msid=100018433497764191308.00046d8bb0be901189fde). When you save KML there will be no points from 6th page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is a 1000 feature limit on exports from My Maps:

[Restrictions](https://sites.google.com/site/gmapstips/alternative-to-paging-on-my-maps)

> #4. There is a 1,000 feature limit on a single My Maps export, and approximately 1,000 
>   in displaying KML - so large maps wont particully benefit from this trick. Wont show an 
>   error just the first 1000 points/lines/features.

See [this post](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/glC0lxDsZ64) on the google map product forum for a workaround to export all the points, Barry Hunter also recommends (and I concur) using FustionTables if you need to display more points on a map (sounds like you don't need to display them on a map, just retrieve the data from your map).

Seems to work, [here](https://maps.google.pl/maps?q=http%3a%2F%2Fwww.geocodezip.com%2Fgeoxml3_test%2FHydranty_big_kml.xml&hl=pl&sll=53.192665,15.445061&sspn=0.091945,0.338173&t=h&gl=pl&z=10) is a combined file displayed on Google Maps (goes up to 1193)

[geoxml3](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/Hydranty_big_kml.xml) reports 1197: geoXmlDoc: Object -> placemarks: Array[1197]